# angular-moment not displaying time properly

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I have below code for displaying date and time.

```
<span>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM' }} Uhr</span>
<span>{{event.modificationDate | amDateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM' }} Uhr</span>
```

and values for each is as below:

```
$scope.event = {
    'date': '2016-11-15T11:13:32+0000',
    'modificationDate': '2016-11-15T11:23:24+0000'
}
```

But its displaying same for both (please refer the screenshot below).

[image]

For 'modificationDate' its displaying wrong time. how to resolve this?
plunker [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1rh2wyra/)

Comment: You have formatted `HH:MM`, which are the months. Instead do it like `HH:mm`

Comment: oh such a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @devqon I guess you can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have formatted your time as `HH:MM`, where the capital M are the months. Instead do it like `HH:mm`:

```
<span>{{event.date | amDateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm' }} Uhr</span>
<span>{{event.modificationDate | amDateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm' }} Uhr</span>
```